# Perl's getpwnam returns deleted entries

Tags: perl, openldap

I am using Perl's [`getpwnam`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/getpwnam.html) to check whether an entry exists in the LDAP database I'm using to store user information. This is used in a script that deletes LDAP entries.

The thing is, when I run the script once, it's successful and I can no longer see the entry via the Unix command `getent passwd` and it's deleted from the LDAP database as well. The problem is, when I try to run the script again and ask it to delete the same user entry (to check that it's idempotent), the `getpwnam` test still returns success (and prints the entry that was just deleted) which causes the script to throw an error about attempting to delete a non-existent entry.

Why is Perl's `getpwnam` behaving like this? Is there a more robust test for LDAP entry existence short of binding to the LDAP server and querying it?

Comment: @WumpusQ.Wumbley You hit the nail on the head sir. `nscd` was the culprit. I stopped it and tried to create a new user and delete it and the behavior was gone. If you will post that as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`nscd` cache is not keeping track of your deletions, apparently.

I'm reluctant to call this an "answer" since I don't know if nscd is *supposed* to stay synchronized with deletions, or how to fix it. The only thing I've ever done with nscd is remove it.

Comment: Thank you. I did a little digging in the `nscd.conf(5)` page and found that a configuration option called `positive-time-to-live` is responsible for this. It was configured to keep the cached entries around for 10 minutes. The strange thing is, `getent passwd` doesn't seem to consult the cache whereas Perl's `getpwnam` does.